# Incomplete results from android.location.geocoder.getFromLocationName()

Tags: android, geocode

This morning I get only incomplete addresses from android.location.geocoder, which is very different from what I would have got yesterday. For example

```
geocoder.getFromLocationName("Burn");
```

returns:

> (java.util.ArrayList) [
>   Address[addressLines=[0:"Lincolnshire",1:"UK"],feature=Lincolnshire,...
>   Address[addressLines=[0:"Lincolnshire",1:"UK"],feature=Lincolnshire,...
>   Address[addressLines=[0:"England",1:"UK"],feature=England,...
>   Address[addressLines=[0:"Great Britain",1:"United Kingdom"],feature=Great Britain,...
>   Address[addressLines=[0:"Great Britain"],feature=Great Britain,...
>   Address[addressLines=[0:"United Kingdom"],feature=United Kingdom...
>   ...
>  
>   ]

What has happened to the detail - all the other address lines? Can I get it back?